# Distribute multiple elements with same class to other elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello need some help to distribute multiple elements with same class to other multiple elements with same class. I think maybe .appendTo can help with this.

I want to move these:
    
    ...

```
<div class="button">
...
</div>

<div class="button">
...
</div>

<div class="button">
...
</div>
```

into these:
    
    ...

```
<div class="button_place">
...
</div>

<div class="button_place">
...
</div>

<div class="button_place">
...
</div>
```

so that I have these:
first button on first button_place and so on...

```
<div class="button_place">
  <div class="button">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button_place">
  <div class="button">
    ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button_place">
  <div class="button">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not just not just 3 elements but 20 at least i need to move this way

Comment: The answers describes only the copy action. To move something means, copy and delete. Do you look for an answer for this action or for copy only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select both sets, loop over one set, and append to the other set.

```js
var buttons = $(".button"),
  places = $(".button_place");

buttons.each(function(i, elem) {
  places.eq(i).append(elem)
})
```

```css
.button_place {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  b1
</div>

<div class="button">
  b2
</div>

<div class="button">
  b3
</div>

<div class="button_place">

</div>

<div class="button_place">

</div>

<div class="button_place">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select all buttons and places. Then iterate over buttons and append them to corresponding places container.

jQuery version:

```
const $places = $('.button_place')

$('.button').each(function(i) {
  $places[i].appendChild(this)
})
```

Pure JS version:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button')
const places  = document.querySelectorAll('.button_place')

buttons.forEach(function(button, index) {
  places[index].appendChild(button)
})
// NodeList.prototype.forEach is not supported in IE,
// convert NodeList to array first with slice, Array.from, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use with `each()` of `$('.button_place')` .and `append($('.button').eq(a).clone()).html()` its used to get the outerhtml of `button`

```js
$('.button_place').each(function(a, b) {
  $(this).append($('.button').eq(a).clone()).html()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button"> button</div>
<div class="button"> button</div>
<div class="button"> button</div>



<div class="button_place">button_place</div>
<div class="button_place">button_place</div>
<div class="button_place">button_place</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using each function as:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6623/

```
$(".button_place").each(function(index,elem){
 //$(elem).html($(".button").eq(0));
 $(elem).append($(".button").eq(0));
})
```

use html function if you want to replace content and use append if you want to add content at the end.